# Is there any post-game content in Rune Factory 4?

Tags: rune-factory-4

I'm wondering what there is to do in RF4 after beating the story.  I'm currently level 59 so it will be difficult to start Arc 2, but is there any sort of activity that I can busy myself with in the meantime?

Comment: Have you started romancing any other character yet? Have you obtained all the cooking recipes? Have you beaten the final boss yet? What arc are you on?

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is busy yourself with preparing for Arcs 2 and 3. Level your crafting skills and work on unlocking all the crops. A little investment in these fields can go a long way in Arcs 2 and 3. Don't forget to explore, there are a few secret areas that you may or may not have found yet.

One of these secret areas is the Demon's Den. It is only accessible in the first week of each season. Beating the boss here will drop a Dungeon Seed, which allows you to grow your own dungeons. Delving into these Plant Dungeons may earn you a Sword or Shield Seed, which you can use to grow Plant Swords and Plant Shields respectively. The stats on these items are completely randomized so you may end up with a Plant Sword with post-post-game stats *far* earlier than is otherwise accessible.

Comment: A good thing to note is you can get items that you're not supposed to be able to get through Dungeon Seeds.  For example, Dungeon Seeds often have many treasure chests within the map.  When I was around level 50, I was getting stuff like Golden Turnip Staff, Water Shoes (allows access to secret areas and allows you to walk on water), something that's only really available late Arc III.   So you can use that to explore parts of the map you haven't finished yet, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What I liked to do was set a routine for myself.  Wake up, check crops, plant as many crops possible (ones that fit well with your current season).   Farm all boss monsters to get the drops, put in stash.  Go to farming spots and gather materials (color grass, lumber, stone) to get upgrades in both skills and your home.

Besides that, as Yuuki mentioned, you can wait for Act II or Act III.  Past Act III there is the level 200 dungeon, similar to the Dungeon seeds you can plant and venture into, but can only be unlocked via PP you get.

If farming isn't something you like, try building up a relationship with everyone else while you wait for the next arc to trigger.  So, talk to everyone you meet at least once a day, try adventuring with them, anything to build up points and unlock additional minievents to trigger other events (relationships, etc).  If you want, you can also look into setting festivals for your town and participating in those.